# How to deploy and interact with a rust websocket?

Tags: heroku, rust, websocket

I'm a beginner in Rust and WebSockets and I'm trying to deploy on Heroku a little chat backend I wrote (everything works on localhost). The build went well and I can see the app is running, and I'm now trying to connect to the WebSocket from a local HTML/Javascript frontend, but it is not working.

Here is my code creating the WebSocket on my rust server on Heroku (using the tungstenite WebSocket crate):

```
async fn main() -> Result<(), IoError> {

    let port = env::var("PORT").unwrap_or_else(|_| "8080".to_string());
    let addr = format!("0.0.0.0:{}", port);

    // Create the event loop and TCP listener we'll accept connections on.
    let try_socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await;
    let listener = try_socket.expect("Failed to bind");
    println!("Listening on: {}", addr);
```

and here is the code in my Javascript file that tries to connect to that WebSocket:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://https://myappname.herokuapp.com/");
```

My web client gets the following error in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://https//rocky-wave-51234.herokuapp.com/' failed
```

I searched to find the answer to my issue but unfortunately didn't find a fix so far. I've found hints that I might have to create an HTTP server first in my backend and then upgrade it to a WebSocket, but I can't find a resource on how to do that and don't even know if this is in fact the answer to my problem. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure if that is the reason, but there is no `wss://https://`. It should be *either* `wss://` or `https://`. So your URL should be `wss://myappname.herokuapp.com/`.

Comment: And yes, your suspicion is correct. A *Websocket* and a *TCP Socket* are two completely different things, you cannot connect to a TCP socket with a websocket client. Websocket is a protocol based on http/https, with `ws` running on top of the unencrypted `http` protocol and `wss` being the encrypted variant which runs on top of `https`. So yes, you need to set up a webserver first which can then upgrade http/https connections to ws/wss websocket connections.

Comment: If you don't want to care about a webserver at all and directly upgrade tcp connections to websocket connections, take a look at [tungstenite](https://crates.io/crates/tungstenite) or its async variant, [tokio-tungstenite](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-tungstenite). If you work with web and io, you probably want to get into async and tokio rather earlier then later. Here's an example: https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/examples/echo-server.rs

Comment: Oh, I'm a bit ashamed, I removed the https:// and it is now working great! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You will still need a websocket library, they way websockets work is they connect to TCP, then upgrade the connection to HTTP, and then upgrade again to websocket. Yes, they connect to your TCP socket, but to actually send data back and forth, you will have to upgrade the connection to websocket.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand things correctly, I currently have a TCP Socket, not a Websocket, is that right? Is there a reason for me to switch to a WebSocket? The final objective is to make a dumb server for a game in Javascript.

Comment: The reason is simple: Browsers are *very* strict with what websites can do. Opening a raw TCP connection is forbidden, as that would have serious safety implications. So websockets are the only sockets you can use from within a javascript based website.

Comment: Oh, so the only reason it's currently working is that my client is not a real website but rather an HTML file locally hosted?

Comment: It isn't working. Yes, it connects, but you aren't yet talking to your javascript code, you are talking to the browser. You only establish a direct connection to the javascript code *after* you upgraded to a websocket in your server. The browser will just drop the connection as soon as you do anything else than upgrade to a websocket, for safety reasons.

Comment: Or did you actually manage to communicate data over the socket? Otherwise I'm not sure what you are refering to with "it's working" :)

Comment: I tried sending messages to the chat and it did work. Maybe I am actually already using a WebSocket? In my handle connection function I have these lines, Am I actually already using Websocket or not?  
let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(raw_stream)
        .await
        .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");
    println!("WebSocket connection established: {}", addr);

Comment: Sorry for the very beginner question and thanks a lot for taking your time to help me this is very helpful to understand how things work!

Comment: Well if you are using tokio_tungstenite, then yes, you are using a websocket :) `tokio_tungstenite::accept_async` is the call that does a the upgrade from TCP to websocket.

Comment: But that means that your example code was definitely not showing all the relevant code.

Comment: No problem, making beginners lives easier is one of the reasons I'm here. Grow the community :)

Comment: Awesome, then I guessed everything is set right! Sorry, I figured only the code for the initialization of the connection would be needed since I wasn't getting past that, my mistake. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Added an actual answer to bring this conversation to a conclusion. If you feel satisfied with it, feel free to add your mark to it to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is the URL you use:

```
"wss://https://myappname.herokuapp.com/"
```

A URL usually starts with `<protocol>://`. The relevant protocols here are:

- `http` - unencrypted hypertext
- `https` - encrypted hypertext
- `ws` - unencrypted websocket
- `wss` - encrypted websocket

So if your URL is an encrypted websocket, it should start *only* with `wss://`, a connection cannot have multiple protocols at once:

```
"wss://myappname.herokuapp.com/"
```